# Update with a subquery and a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I update `table1` with results of this query -

```
select b.description from 
table1 c
join 
(
    SELECT distinct a.hcpc, a.description
    FROM table2 a 
) b 
on b.hcpc = c.hcpc
where c.description = '0'
```

I want to do something like this -

```
update table1 
set table1.description = (select b.description from table1 c
join 
(
    SELECT distinct a.hcpc, a.description
    FROM table2 a 
) b 
on b.hcpc = c.hcpc
where c.description = '0'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered many times in SO... anyway, the query should be built this way

One option

```
update table1 c
set description = b.description
from
  (
    SELECT distinct a.hcpc, a.description
    FROM table2 a 
  ) b  
where b.hcpc = c.hcpc
  and c.description = '0'
```

Other option

```
with t as (
  SELECT distinct a.hcpc, a.description
  FROM table2 a
)
update table1 c
set description = t.description
from t
where t.hcpc = c.hcpc
  and c.description = '0'
```

Surely there are other additional ways...